# Iterative usage of expand.grid in R

Tags: r, iteration, combinations

I'd like to know if there's any way to use the expand.grid() function (or any other one) to generate all the possible combinations for a specified number of sequences. The latter is given by the user.

**Desired result.** For example,

```
expand.grid(0:1, 0:1)
  Var1 Var2
1    0    0
2    1    0
3    0    1
4    1    1

expand.grid(0:1, 0:1, 0:1)
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    0    0    0
2    1    0    0
3    0    1    0
4    1    1    0
5    0    0    1
6    1    0    1
7    0    1    1
8    1    1    1

expand.grid(0:1, 0:1, 0:1, ...)
  Var1 Var2 Var3 ...
1    0    0    0 ...
2    1    0    0 ...
3    0    1    0 ...
4    1    1    0 ...
5    0    0    1 ...
6    1    0    1 ...
7    0    1    1 ...
8    1    1    1 ...
.    .    .    .
.    .    .    .
.    .    .    .
```

**NOTE**: the implementation is not limited to 0-1 sequences, so it should also work for something like `expand.grid(0:1, 0:5, 2:4, 3:5)`

**My implementation.** I was trying something like this:

```
expand.grid(rep(0:1, 3))
```

But R interprets this as a single sequence:

```
  Var1
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    1
5    0
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can `rep` the `list` and then do `expand.grid`

```
expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),3))
#  Var1 Var2 Var3
#1    0    0    0
#2    1    0    0
#3    0    1    0
#4    1    1    0
#5    0    0    1
#6    1    0    1
#7    0    1    1
#8    1    1    1
```

Or another option would be using `replicate` with `simplify=FALSE` to return a `list` output and then use `expand.grid`

```
expand.grid(replicate(3, 0:1, simplify=FALSE))
```